# How do I copy text from window text editor to nano/vi in a Putty window

Tags: ssh, putty, vi, nano

I was following some guide to create key-pair for my remote linux system, one of the steps being copy the public key generated and saved on my local computer to the `authorized-keys` file on remote computer. 
I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to nano/vi editor in the "putty" window, but it doesn't work(nothing appears in the editor). Do I really have to manually type in the keys or there is some other way to copy and paste it?

Answer (score 9):

You can of course use the mouse, but that runs the risk of accidentally selecting/pasting due to mouse-movement.

PuTTY recognizes <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> for pasting from the clipboard.  This works reliably (key bounce is rare).  You can also change the behavior of the right-click to get a menu, as noted in Greg Ferro's page.

Further reading:

- [Putty – Fixing Right Click Paste](http://etherealmind.com/putty-fixing-right-click-paste/)
- [How-to Copy and Paste With Putty](https://conetrix.com/Blog/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-putty)

Answer (score 3):

If you've got content from another application copied into the clipboard on your local machine, right-click anywhere within the PuTTY window to paste it into the remote shell.

Note: instead of pasting the key into a text editor, you can use echo and redirect its output to `authorized-keys`, like so: `echo [paste your public key here] >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. In the past, I've had issues pasting into nano/vim with PuTTY (though they may have fixed that behavior).

Answer (score 2):

Try shift-right clicking instead.

I, too, found that right-click alone would not work (in nano)--even though right-clicking at the terminal WOULD paste the clipboard. And I found all kinds of suggestions of things to try (ctrl-shift-v, shift-insert), none of which would work. Finally, I found someone suggesting shift-right click, and it worked without any needed mods. Salvation when one has to insert long or multiple lines from outside the editor!

That said, I found some multi-line text would paste while some would not. In that case, if I pasted it a couple of lines at a time, it worked. Odd. Sharing that in case it may help someone else, or they may know what was up.

Answer (score 1):

you can login FTP wit Winscp(in Windows) or Filzilla (in Linux) and go to file **.ssh/authorized_keys** end open it and copy . is better and these Software are helpful and fast to change files

Answer (score 0):

In all place, `nano` editor works the same!

Lines can be cut with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> (copied with <kbd>Alt + ^</kbd>) and paste with <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>.